# Google Sheets Custom Function for Arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a custom function in Google sheets that searches a column range for a specific value and returns true if it does. I've tested the function and it works fine when run in the script editor, however when I try to utilize it in Google sheets it does not work.

When I define the array argument the function runs fine, but when I try to pass a range in Google sheets as an array the function always returns false. This is my first time coding with Javascript/Google sheets functions, so I know I must be doing something wrong but I can't figure out exactly what the issue is. According to the [developer page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), passing a range of cells should automatically make an array as far as I understand, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

So,

=columnMatch(A2; "hello", "hi", "good morning") will return true, BUT

=columnMatch(A2; B2:B) will always return false.

(where A2 is defined as "hi", and column B contains the list of values I wish to test for)

My code for the custom function is below:

````
**function columnMatch(submittedLocation, locationlist)** 
{
  
  for(var i = 0; i < locationlist.length; i++)
  {
     if(locationlist.includes(submittedLocation)) 
      return true; 
  }

  return false; 
} ```
````

Comment: If you are working on this script simply as a means to learn scripting, carry on. However, if you are working on the script because you need to perform the function, there are already built-in functions that do this, e.g., =REGEXMATCH(A2, "hello|hi|good morning")

Comment: You can make the above formula suggestion case agnostic as well: =REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2), "hello|hi|good morning") ... or apply it to an entire range, e.g., =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2:A), "hello|hi|good morning"))) ... or you can place the list of match words in a range and use the following version: =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2:A), JOIN("|",TRIM(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))))))

Comment: @ErikTyler - I think your comments should be an answer.

Comment: I considered that, andrewjames; but since the original post is specifically asking about a scripted custom function, my feedback doesn't technically constitute an answer. If the OP indicates that this fills the need, however, I will post as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this to a one-line function:

```js
function columnMatch(submittedLocation, locationlist) {
  return locationlist.flat().filter(String).includes(submittedLocation);
}
```

How this works:

The `submittedLocation` is a single value.

The `locationlist` is a range - a 2-dimensional array of values:

```
[ ["val1"], ["val2"], [...], ... ]
```

To handle the 2-D list of words, we first [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it to a simple array.

Then we [filter out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) any empty values to avoid a very large array with not much actual data in it. We keep only non-empty strings. This step is not required, but is recommended.

Finally we can see if our search value is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the array - and just return the `true`/`false` result of that boolean test.